# jQuery Height broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, window

> Take a look at this:
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/3FaVN/
>
> 1. Try resizing the result vertically: the two columns scroll correctly afterwards.
> 2. Next resize horizontally, and then try resizing vertically again: **notice how the columns are no longer equal to the viewport height and do not scroll correctly.**

I do not understand what is happening here.

My javascript seems easy enough:

```
function setHeight() {
     $('.panel').height( $(window).height() );
}

$(window).load(setHeight).resize(setHeight);
```

​
Anyone know what is causing this? Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Protip: when you're using a popular library to do a basic thing and it's not behaving the way you expect, it's extremely unlikely that you're the first person who has noticed this "bug" -- it's much more likely that you have a bug in your code, or that your expectations of the function are mistaken.

Comment: That said, I have no idea why it's doing that. I agree it seems odd.

Comment: I've been using jQuery for a long time and for the past hour I've been searching and diving into the jquery script and it doesn't make sense. Of course I'm not the only one to try and do this **[before](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/ScZ5S/)** however I cannot figure out why script that should work exactly the same isnt

Comment: @JamesKyle: Never mind, I failed to see the height issue at first I thought there was an issue scrolling or something :) I saw the issue now and added a fix in my answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `height: 100%;` instead of `height: inherit;` on your `.scroll` divs

Answer (score 0):

jQuery resize is working fine as height of 'div.panel' is correct. it is internal divs of 'div.panel' whose height is not proper.
Setting children height will solve the problem modified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FaVN/22/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery works fine; `.panel`'s height is set correctly. Its children, however, are not being set at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your event was fired by resize, just put console.log. I don't know why but this work http://jsfiddle.net/3FaVN/24/

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in webkit with display: table(-cell) and resizing, see https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53166 .

I would stay far from display: table for now.

EDIT: after reading some more, I'm not sure this applies to your situation. To me though, after testing quite a bit, it does feel like a bug in webkit of some sorts (as in: it's broken, and after some element inspection, things seem to work again...)